# How to catch TimeoutError using Pulsar HttpClient with Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, python-asyncio, python-pulsar

I'm writing an app using Tornado. I need to make a lot of HTTP requests, but Tornado's HTTP client sucks a bit (doesn't have Keep-Alive support and is slow), so I'm trying to use Pulsar HttpClient:

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.gen
import tornado.httpserver
from tornado.platform.asyncio import AsyncIOMainLoop
from tornado.platform import asyncio as tornasync
import asyncio
from pulsar.apps import http as pulsar_http


class MyHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        http_client = self.application.http_client

        future = tornasync.to_tornado_future(asyncio.async(http_client.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org', timeout=.25)))
        try:
            result = yield future
        except TimeoutError as e:
            print('Timeout!')

        print(result.get_content())

        self.write('OK')
        self.finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AsyncIOMainLoop().install()

    app = tornado.web.Application([(r'/', MyHandler)], debug=False)
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    server.bind(8888)
    server.start(1)

    app.http_client = pulsar_http.HttpClient(loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Bun when a timeout occurs, I get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vitaliy/.virtualenvs/tornado/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1415, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "/home/vitaliy/.virtualenvs/tornado/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/vitaliy/.virtualenvs/tornado/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/home/vitaliy/.virtualenvs/tornado/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 876, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "bpp.py", line 19, in get
    result = yield future
  File "/home/vitaliy/.virtualenvs/tornado/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/vitaliy/.virtualenvs/tornado/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 300, in _step
    result = coro.send(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 436, in wait_for
    raise futures.TimeoutError()
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError
```

Can I catch this exception somehow?

Comment: where are you importing TimeoutError from? It looks like it's not imported.

Comment: have you tried `from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError`?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, Oh, thanks, it works!. At first i thought that it's the same as a built-in TimeoutError. Turns out, it isn't.

Comment: @vitaly converting to an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import that error into your code:

```
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
```

Otherwise you can't catch it